# how to stop an already running animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am doing some animation using block level technique. I want to stop the animation on the basis of certain condition. How will I stop the animation from completing?

Following is my code for animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{ 
                         if([arrAns count]>0)
                             vwb1.center = CGPointMake(260, 40);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                          animations:^{ 
                                              if([arrAns count]>1)
                                                  vwb2.center = CGPointMake(260, 100);
                                          } 
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                                               animations:^{ 
                                                                   if([arrAns count]>2)
                                                                       vwb3.center = CGPointMake(260, 160);
                                                               } 
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                                                                    animations:^{ 
                                                                                        if([arrAns count]>3)
                                                                                            vwb4.center = CGPointMake(260, 220);
                                                                                    } 
                                                                                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{ 
                                                                                            if([arrAns count]>4)
                                                                                                vwb5.center = CGPointMake(260, 280);
                                                                                        } completion:nil];
                                                                                    }];
                                                               }];

                                          }
                          ];

                     }];
```

I am not having any key here so I can nnot remove it on the basis of a key. There is also a feature as removeallanimation but I am not able to use it. If someone could help me on how to use that it will also be fine.

**Edit:** Ok I figured out how to do it, I am doing it using following code:

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

But now I have problem that my block level animation which have not yet started is still running. So if I remove the animation at second block it still executes remaining block. I need to stop that also.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Did you try removeallanimations?

Comment: @Praveen please check my message now. I have an update...

Comment: you have to stop the animations for all the layers seperately.

Answer (score 2):

You should check `finished` variable. And start next animation (inside a block) only if previous was finished (`finished == YES`), not stopped.

> `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`
>
> ...
>
> ***completion***
>    A block object to be executed when the animation sequence
>   ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean
>   argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually
>   finished before the completion handler was called. If the duration of
>   the animation is 0, this block is performed at the beginning of the
>   next run loop cycle.